# While loop to continue taking user input from stringstream after calling print function

Tags: c++

My program uses a stringstream to store data to a vector of strings, which is used to pass values to a print function. The user will type in 5 items from standard input, for example: summary DAL 2 5 54. Afterwards enter is pressed and I take each of these 5 items and pass them to a summary function.

```
string line;
getline(cin, line);
stringstream ss(line);
string tmp;

vector<string> cmd;
int DOWN; 
int TOGO; 
int YDLINE;

ss >> tmp;       //BEGIN INPUT
while(ss)
{
    cmd.push_back(tmp);  //STORE TO VECTOR OF STRINGS
    ss >> tmp;
}

ss.clear();
ss.str( cmd[2]  );
ss >> DOWN; //CONVERT STRING TO INT

ss.clear();
ss.str( cmd[3]  );
ss >> TOGO; //STRING TO INT

ss.clear();
ss.str( cmd[4]  );
ss >> YDLINE; //STRING TO INT


summary(cmd[0], cmd[1], DOWN, TOGO, YDLINE, TeamData); //PASS VALUES TO PRINT FUNCTION
```

I'm trying to return from the print function so that the program continues taking input after printing for as long as the user inputs data. I'm struggling with creating a proper loop. The only loop that didn't crash my program was if i did something like the following, but all it did was cause an infinite print loop.

```
while(ss >> tmp)
{
 while(ss)
{
    cmd.push_back(tmp);
    ss >> tmp;
}
. . .

. . .

summary(cmd[0], cmd[1], DOWN, TOGO, YDLINE, TeamData); //PASS VALUES TO PRINT FUNCTION
}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**stringstream.clear()** is used to reset error flags and not clear the stream, although it might be giving you results but it's meaning shouldn't be changed.

```
#include<cstdlib>

 char ch;
 string line;
 string buf;
 bool check=true;

 cout<<"Enter input\n";

 while(1)
 {
   if(check == true)
   {
     cin>>line;
   }
   else break;
   istringstream is(line);

   // This will split the line based on whitespace
   while(std::getline(is, buf, ' '))
   {
     cmd.push_back(buf);

     // Checking if vector has 5 elements

     if(cmd.size() == 5)
     {
       // Call function summary
       summary(cmd[0], cmd[1], atoi(cmd[2].c_str()), atoi(cmd[3].c_str()),   
       atoi(cmd[4].c_str()), TeamData);

       // Clear the vector list now
       cmd.clear();

       cout<<"Do you want to continue, enter y then"<<endl;
       cin>>ch;
       if(ch == 'y')
       { 
         cout<<"Enter input"<<endl;
       }
       else
       {
         check=false;
         break;
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

**atoi** function would convert your string to integer type.

Comment: i think we're on the right track, but it's waiting for 5 inputs (presses of the enter key) from the user instead of 5 items. i apologize for leaving that out of my original post. the user is going to type in 5 items from standard input, for example: summary DAL 2 5 54. Afterwards enter is pressed and I then take each of these 5 items and pass them to my summary function

Comment: i kno we're not supposed to say thanks, but YOU SAVED MY SANITY! thank you. i'll need to brush up on my knowledge of stringstream, getline, etc but now i can finally continue this program!

Comment: @GeorgeCostanza I did some formatting changes, please check the latest edit.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you want something like

```
while (std::getline(...))
{
    // ...

    while (ss >> tmp)
        cmd.push_back(tmp);

    // ...

    summary(...);
}
```